# PasteboardPutItemFlavor Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument

Tags: xcode, macos, clipboard, macos-carbon

I know there are plenty of questions asking about how to solve "Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument", but I really can't seem to find a solution for my problem.

I use a function called PasteboardPutItemFlavor in my code. It compiles alright if I set the deploy target to 10.12 built against macSDK10.12. After I set the deploy target to 10.8, but still compile it against macSDK10.12, I got an error on PasteboardPutItemFlavor call. The error message is "Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument". What does this error mean? kPasteboardFlavorNoFlags is defined as 0, changing to other constant value doesn't change anything.

How do I solve this error with 10.8 as deploy target and compile against 10.12?

```
PasteboardPutItemFlavor(
            m_pboard,
            nullptr,
            flavorType,
            dataRef,
            kPasteboardFlavorNoFlags);
```

The function declaration is

```
OSStatus PasteboardPutItemFlavor(PasteboardRef inPasteboard, PasteboardItemID inItem, CFStringRef inFlavorType, CFDataRef inData, PasteboardFlavorFlags inFlags);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the header file from 10.12 SDK. The header file is warped with nonnull macro. So any pointer with that macro would be declared as nonnull. In my case is the nullptr parameter. I simply create a local variable and set to 0 then pass it in PasteboardPutItemFlavor. That solves the error.